# How could I remove * infront of digits in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am working with xml and xsl to format the file and couldn't figure out how I could remove asterisk infront of the SSNs. Asterisks are there sometimes and sometimes its just digits. I want to make sure there is no asterisks in SSNs. How do I remove asterisk?

Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLAsterisk.xsl"?>
<information>
    <secondBranch>
        <SSN>771717771</SSN>
    </secondBranch>
    <secondBranch>
        <SSN>9991</SSN>
    </secondBranch>
    <secondBranch>
        </SSN>
    </secondBranch>
</information>
```

Example XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <title>
            </title>
            <body>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        SSN
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/information/secondBranch">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:value-of select="SSN"/>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </body>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There's no code here, so presumably you'll use a text editor to do it. Any programmatic solution will be language-specific, but you haven't specified even that.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Comment: The XML example you show is not a well-formed XML document!

Comment: Added the header on the xml

Comment: @michael.hor257k You live & learn. Didn't know about that. Thank you

Comment: Could you take away the dislike

Comment: @bugsaccount The "header", as you call it, has nothing to do with it. You have several `xsl:if` start-tags without closing and without binding the `xsl` prefix to a namespace. It doesn't seem likely that they are truly in the real input XML.

Comment: Oh, and the last SSN has only an end-tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make sure there is no asterisks in SSNs.

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(SSN, '*', '')"/>
```